# how to create broadcast variable in spark 2(java)?

Tags: java, apache-spark-2.0

In Spark 1 we can use the below code to create a Spark broadcast variable:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "JavaAPISuite", conf);

ArrayList<Strin'valuesg> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
sampleList.add("value");

final Broadcast<ArrayList<String> broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(sampleList);
```

How can we do the same in Spark 2 using the API shown below?

```
SparkSession sc = SparkSession.setappName("SparkApp").getorcreate();
sc.sparkcontext().broadcast(T value, scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$11)
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: hi cricket_007...the link shows the  Spark 1 type...not the SparkSession of Spark2

Comment: What do you mean? You need a SparkContext to broadcast. You get the context from the Spark session

Comment: You copied the function wrong, by the way. There's one parameter, the value... The implicit argument can be ignored  `broadcast[T](value: T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Broadcast[T]`

Comment: @cricket_007...as per spark api documentation for Java ,i needs to input parameters for creating a broadcast variable..as given below         <T> Broadcast<T>  broadcast(T value, scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$11)
Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a Broadcast object for reading it in distributed functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example if you want to broadcast class named `Test` it should implement `java.io.Serializable` and then you do:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag;

ClassTag<Test> classTagTest = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Test.class);
Broadcast<Test> broadcastTest = sc.sparkcontext().broadcast(new Test(), classTagTest);
```